# How to redirect to the base URL if the given URL ends with a slash?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect

I have this link http://localhost:3007/sellers-toolkit/, but the right page is only the one without a trailing slash. So I would like a redirection to http://localhost:3007/sellers-toolkit.

I tried to write this part in JavaScript, but it just makes the page reload and nothing happens. What is the right way to achieve this behavior?

```
var url = "http://localhost:3007/sellers-toolkit/";
if (url) {
  url = "http://localhost:3007/sellers-toolkit";
  window.location.href = url;
}
```

Comment: "it just make the page reloading". What else are you expecting to happen? If someone types in the address in the address bar with the / in it, you can't use JS to solve this because JS runs in the page (unless you are using node.JS??), and if that URL doesn't load the page, then there's no page in which to execute the JS. QED. You need to implement some sort of rewrite rule, either in your server config or within some code which can respond to that URL.

Comment: I am actually using node yes do could you guide me where i check if i am using node?

Comment: Are you using Express?

Comment: "I am actually using node yes do could you guide me where i check if i am using node?". ??? If you know you're using node, why do you need to check whether you're using node? You already know.

Comment: i fixed it guys on my server side of node like that . : if (req.url == '/sellers-toolkit' || req.url == '/sellers-toolkit/' ) {
        category = 'Selling Privately';
    } . easy simple :D

Comment: Have a look at Express ... It makes such questions obvious

Comment: @Jonasw: https://github.com/ericf/express-slash

Comment: @badacabra %facepalm% ...

Comment: @HeshamElMasry a note that isn't super related, it's suggested to use the strict `===` instead of the `==`, type conversions can lead to [unexpected results](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/)

Answer (score 0):

my solution for this issue is that i was trying to do that on the javascript side but i found that i have to do this on my node server side.

i used this code:

```
if (req.url == '/sellers-toolkit' || req.url == '/sellers-toolkit/' ) {
        category = 'Selling Privately';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

```
var url = "http://localhost:3007/sellers-toolkit/";
var spe_char_last =url.substr(url.length - 1);
if(spe_char_last == '/')
{
url = url.slice(0, -1);
if (url) {
  url = "http://localhost:3007/sellers-toolkit";
  window.location.href = url;
}
}
```

Comment: hope i understood correctly.please tell me comments?